# Match Orthographic along normals?

Tags: 3d-view, orthographic

If i were to rotate cube 23 degrees then go to orthographic view, it would be difficult to line up the viewfinder (in orthographic) to be flush with the object. Is there a function that makes this easier or does this for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> will align your view to the normals of a selected face.

Comment: ..actually it's Shift np7 for the front of the face, Ctrl-Shift-np7 for its back .. just a small tweak

Comment: Haha, didn't know that.